# set password for one sheet of workbook (MS Excel 2007)

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I need to set a password for only one sheet in xls file, so when the file is open the sheet protected with password isn't visible, and the other sheets could be seen.

I use MS Excel 2007, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA Edidor set the Property `Visible` of your sheet to `2 - xlSheetVeryHidden` so the user can't see the sheet when the file is opened

See also: http://www.excel-university.com/make-an-excel-worksheet-very-hidden

Comment: but in this case, even if the sheet is set to be hidden the user can make the sheet visible without entering the password  ?

Comment: why haven't you tried it by yourself? the user can make it visible by setting the `Visible` to `1 - xlSheetVisible`. But you can protect your VBA project with a password so the user can't change the `Visible` property without your password